# Rails Multiple DB Calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 4 app I have a `bookings` table and a `currencies` table. Each booking `has_one` currency.

When I display all bookings on a page (including the currency) I have noticed that it makes a separate call to the DB for each booking which I'm a little concerned about.

Here is some code:

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <%= booking.currency.code %>
<% end %>
```

While I'm sure performance isn't going to be massively affected I just wondered if anyone recommends against this approach and has a better approach in order to reduce calls to the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should eager load currencies, with `includes` method:

```
@bookings = Booking.your_scope.includes(:currency)
```

Comment: I've not encountered eager load yet!

Comment: @tommyd456 I wrote how you should do it.

Comment: The association seems to be named "currency", not "currencies" => `.includes(:currency)`

Comment: Ok def the way to go but I've got an issue...I have `@bookings = Booking.pending_bookings_for current_user.accommodation_id` which includes a parameter so I'm not sure where I can put the `.includes(:currency)` part?

Comment: @tommyd456 basically anywhere. :) It's just appending scope to `ActiveRecord::Relation` - scope sequence doesn't matter.
For, example, it can be:
`@bookings = Booking.pending_bookings_for(current_user.accomodation_id).includes(:currency)`

Comment: ok and finally - there is also an association with a guest table where guests have many bookings - can you add multiple includes? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: @tommyd456 yes, you can pass an array of symbols, like this:
`@bookings = Booking.includes([:currency, :guest])`.